# Is the "On hold" message sometimes wrong?

Tags: support, close-reasons, vote-to-close, closed-questions

Looking at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307879/does-linux-operating-systems-not-run-as-hot-as-windows-10 I see the question has been marked as "put on hold as unclear what you're asking by Thomas Dickey, jasonwryan, Stephen Harris, Scott, Jeff Schaller 7 mins ago"

But I marked it as "primarily opinion based" (because it's very very dependent on the hardware, the drivers, the OS version...).

The reason for being put on hold is now attributing to me a statement I didn't make.

(This isn't the first time I've seen this; just the first time I've been motivated to ask :-))

Is this a site issue, or am I misunderstanding the message?

Comment: The ayes have it: the reason that garners the most votes is the one that is published (in cases where more than one was selected by the voters).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What Jasonwryan said. When more than one close reason has been chosen by the people who voted to close, the most popular one is shown. I'm not sure what happens if each voter chose a different one and we end up with 5 separate reasons, but in all other cases, there will be at least one reason with more votes and that's the one which will be shown.

Comment: The 2-2-1 spread of votes is another way of getting a tie :-)  But I get the point.

Comment: @StephenHarris d'oh! Indeed :)

Comment: Ties are resolved in favor of the last vote (that was cast for one of the plurality reasons).

Comment: @Giles Thanks; I think I understand the determinism now.  It's still saying something I didn't, but I understand the logic :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue; you are not the only one who dislikes having your name associated with an opinion you may not share.

If you are so inclined, I suggest you add your voice to the discussion on Meta of this subject:

- [Distinguish close votes by reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54917/307622)

Comment: Interesting thread; I think the "I didn't say that" position has been adequately expressed :-)